# SSRS - Empty Page if no data in Data Source?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, reporting-services, mdx, business-intelligence

I have a report where if the user has no data in the data source, the user sees empty page. There are 5 Tables. I tried to use NoRowsMessage but it still shows empty page.

If there is no data in the source for a particular user, is there a way to show some message?

Thank you

Comment: You could union the select to single row but that is so ugly I am not even going to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Tbx1.NoRowsMessage = "No Data returned for this section."
```

Should work.

You can force it the old school method.  Add a textbox above the section and show it when hiding the tablix.

```
TextBox1.Text = "No Data returned for this section."
TextBox1.Hidden = IIf(Sum(Fields!SOME_ID.value, "SOME_DATA_SET")<>0, False, True)

Tbx1.Hidden = IIf(Sum(Fields!SOME_ID.value, "SOME_DATA_SET")<>0, True, False)
```

Assumes that SOME_ID is always a positive number.

TextBoxs do not have a .NoRowsMessage.

Comment: Text boxes have NoRowMessage property?